# How can I schedule the User Profile Service to run a full sync weekly?

Tags: 2010, powershell, user-profile-service, timer-jobs

We are running SharePoint Server 2010 and have not yet applied SP1. User profile incremental sync is not picking up all of the group membership from AD. Starting a full sync seems to rectify the syncronization. So the latest wisdom seems to be to run a full sync weekly before compiling audiences.

Can I create a timer job to run a full sync?

Comment: Wow. Great question. I wasn't aware of the limitation and hadn't thought full synchronization was so necessary before you asked.

Answer (score 8):

Just to accomplish what John said, you can create a schedules task for the following PowerShell script:

```
$UserProfileService= Get-SPServiceApplication 42gg4bda-1hd0-4df6-bfgg-54gd4df33ff
$UserProfileService.StartImport($true)
```

**P.S.** Full Import can be intensive though so be very careful with the schedule.

Comment: Remember to replace the guid/id with the one for your system. Or grab the service by name like this: 
$UserProfileService= Get-SPServiceApplication | where { $_.DisplayName -eq "User Profile Service Application"}

Answer (score 4):

You could create a PowerShell script to run the Full Profile Sync and then schedule it to run as a Windows Scheduled Task every week.

Comment: +1 I have updated the PowerShell script

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak to 2007, in the Shared Service Provider you can configure full and incremental imports of user data.  Is this not an option in the 2010 User Profile Service?  If it's there, you can set up a weekly full import on any day/time that you wish and set daily incremental imports.

Since it looks like this is not an option any longer, the timer job or scheduled PowerShell script might be th eonly options.

Comment: In SP 2010 there is only one schedule for imports and it is Incremental - no option to make it Full. :-(

Answer (score -2):

Well you should be able to set it up using the "Configure Synchronization Timer Job" from the User Profile Service application.

[image]

Comment: As your screenshot shows, this is the Incremental Synch