# Active Directory Integration with Sharepoint

Tags: active-directory, user-profile-service, integration

I have a SharePoint site  with  my company's active directory integration. When new personnel start to work, he/she is defined in AD. Then the record comes to SharePoint automatically.

If personnel information needs to be changed, it can changed in AD. But this change doesn't propagate to SharePoint site. Namely, if the name or surname needs to be changed, in AD it is corrected, but not reflected in SharePoint.

How can I change personnel information in SharePoint Designer/Central Administration?
[image]

Sharepoint 2013 Management Shell

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change it in Central Adminsitration > Application Management > Manage service applications > User Profile Service Application > Manage User Profiles.

But you should investigate why attributes from AD accounts aren't synchronized properly. If one day synchronization between AD and SharePoint gets fixed then changes you made manually in Central Administration might be overwritten.

Comment: I tried this solve but when I want to find a user profile, it find only admin's user profile. It can't find other user's profile. I want to change other users information.

Comment: This means you don't have synchronization between AD and SharePoint setup properly. For details take a look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I can't synchronization again because I'm afraid my site user permissions and profiles can break down. Here is a big company and if the intergration wrong I stayed in a difficult situation. Is there any way?

Comment: If you want first name, last name, etc. attributes synchronized from AD then you have to configure Synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

NO Slaven is incorrect! this is one way, any changes you make through sharepoint would not make any changes through AD! You should only need to make changes through AD and let Sharepoint handle the rest ;)

Sharepoint like its search counterpart need the same process in AD user profile updating! i think what your looking for is 'Schedule profile synchronization'

through PowerShell:

full code:

```
 $UserProfileService= Get-SPServiceApplication | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'User Profile Service Application' }
 $UserProfileService.StartImport($true)
```

[How can I schedule the User Profile Service to run a full sync weekly?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/how-can-i-schedule-the-user-profile-service-to-run-a-full-sync-weekly)

the code above would only sync once tho! so as john noted to setup Windows Scheduled Task to run the script every night or weekend!

for 2013  or 2010:

This is to set a timed schedule to run! this should be set over night or over weekend as it can be heavy on system!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890103.aspx

**UPDATE**

your error relates to not loading the lib for sharepoint snapin!

two options here! one add it through code or two load sharepoint powershell:

1)

add this code first before any other code:

```
 Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
 $UserProfileService= Get-SPServiceApplication | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'User Profile Service Application' }
 $UserProfileService.StartImport($true)
```

if code runs fine then you need to stick it into a text file, copy code above and paste into text file. Next you need to save the file... give it a meaningfull name and save. Next goto the file location and change the .txt part to .ps1 ... it should now be a powershell script file instead of a file. You can then setup a Windows Scheduled Task to execute the file when ever you want :) . If you have notepad++ than you can create a new file and just save it with the .ps1 extention instead!

2)

run this powershell instead:

[image]

**EDIT**

please make sure that the connection now exists!

goto:

Central Adminsitration > Application Management > Manage service applications > User Profile Service Application > Manage User Profiles > select 'Configure Synchronization Connections'

[image]

once loaded make sure you can see the connection, if you can than its setup and you can click on it to edit..

[image]

[image]

once in the edit screen you should be able to see some setup configs for domains and user account name that you would use to connect with.

first step is make sure that your setup is correct:

make sure:

'type' is set to 'active directory'

'Authentication' is set to 'windows authentication'

put in a valid account name and password that is at farm level for now.

now the important part is the containers section. please see if you have any populated?

if not click on 'populate container' this should connect to AD with the account details above and populate all AD containers. if the grandparent is checked, uncheck and recheck... if its unchecked than just check it. you can select any other container you wish or deselect as you wish. This will sync the containers with sharpoint.

once finished click on the OK button below and you should be all good to go!

image is a bit messy but contains all important parts, as you can see all containers are loaded and it has a tick around the group that i need and the grandparent is ticked

[image]

let me know if you get into any issues!

Comment: Please look at my second paragraph where I emphasize that synchronization should be fixed.

Comment: I tried this but I got error. I added screenshot under my question. Could you analyze the error,please?

Comment: @aliSharePoint, actually your answer is incorrect. There is a two way sync: http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/05/31/does-sharepoint-2010-mess-with-my-active-directory/

Comment: @zengel you need to open powershell with sharepoint addin, or add this code first: Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

Comment: @aliSharepoint I did this.

Comment: @SlavenSemper please read up properly on this subject as your refering to two-way synchronization where the op hasnt even got one way yet! infact most companies and setups dont have two way as its preferd that AD handle user profiles and sharepoint to get those changes not the other way round.

Comment: @aliSharepoint, this is a citation from your answer: "NO Slaven is incorrect! this is one way, any changes you make through sharepoint would not make any changes through AD!"

Comment: @zengel just updated the ps code, please let me know if its still showing the error!

Comment: @SlavenSemper yes I know and you need to read your answer why i posted that as its true nothing would be updated! the op is not asking for changes to be made on sharepoint the op is asking for the changes to be synced through sharepoint from AD! You answer is wrong and only updates sharepoint, when a sync occures it would lose any changes made on sharepoint!

Comment: @aliSharepoint Should I run your powershell code, now?
$UserProfileService= Get-SPServiceApplication | ? { $_.TypeName -eq 'User Profile Service Application' }
 $UserProfileService.StartImport($true)

Comment: @aliSharepoint I don't mean to be disrespectful in any way. I think this might be the case of bad English. From your first paragraph one might come to conclusion that two way sync is not possible. That's all.

Comment: @zengel yes. ive updated my answer for you with full code to run or other option :)

Comment: @aliSharepoint, btw op doesn't have sync set up at all :)

Comment: @aliSharepoint what can i do then? I run the your powershell code.

Comment: @zengel yes but if you do it will run a profile Synchronization against AD! it will import all profiles into sharepoint!

Comment: @zengel has it run without error?

Comment: @aliSharepoint Yes I got error and I added under my question the error.

Comment: @zengel looks like its already running! let it run through and hopefully all is ok! once ok you need to follow as noted above to schedule the script to run either daily at nite or weekly over weekend to reduce work load on server!

Comment: @aliSharepoint thanks for helps. I have a question. The question may sound silly to you, sorry. But I'm new on SharePoint and I ask again and again. Please answer to me again :) Recently I made process is enough,even if I do not add timer? Does it solve the problem?

Comment: @zengel thats fine as as much as you need! i didnt quite get what you mean? it will solve your issue for now! its will run this once but only once and you will need to run it again every time to update sharpeoint hence why you need to setup timerjob thruogh User Profile Service Application or by Windows Scheduled Task to run your script! this way it will always update without you needing to manually do this and will run out of ours to reduce load on servers!

Comment: @aliSharepoint thanks for advice. You're right. I add scheduled. I write to you. :)

Comment: no problem happy to help!

Comment: @aliSharepoint hi. I tried to your advice then I controlled incorrect user profiles. But their name and surname doesn't change. It isn't working my site. Why isn't it?

Comment: @zengel just updated my answer!

Comment: @aliSharepoint I'm using Sharepoint 2013 and when I click the 'Configure Synchronization Connections' there isn't connection in the list. And then I clicked "Create New Collection" I got this error "Cannot navigate to the requested page while User Profile Synchronization is running. Please wait for the current  Synchronization run to finish." Then I clicked OK. It is redirecting to User Profile Service page. It isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you encountered is due to the fact that the UserInfo table is not updated for the current site collection.

For your case, I believe you haven't set up the User Profile Synchronization Service Application yet. When you update the user information in the AD server, e.g. DisplayName, in order for the information to be reflected in the SharePoint site, you need to run the following command:

```
Set-SPUser -identity "domain\UserA" -SyncFromAD
```

After running the command in the SharePoint Management Shell, the change will be reflected in the SharePoint site.

Comment: Ngheim I tried your solve. But I got warning and I added under my questions with title of Sharepoint Management Shell. Can you controlled this? What should i do?

Comment: You need to replace "domain\UserA" with actual user ID. Which users did you update the information?

Comment: for example domain:kuhah username:zengel --> in that case kuhah\zengel . Is it true? @Randy

Comment: Yes, you should run as Set-SPUser -identity "kuhah\zengel" -SyncFromAD

Comment: I got warning and I added under my questions with title of Sharepoint Management Shell. Can you controlled this? What should i do?  @Randy